# SurveyMonkey API - Console issue

Tags: api, oauth, surveymonkey

im trying to test the Survey Monkey api via the online test console but keep getting the following error:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/io-docs   (link)

It's asking me to enter the Authorisation:

Content-Type:
Authorization: bearer %s <--- not sure where to get this from? (Access token)
api_key:
JSON:

and so im getting a "errmsg": "Invalid \"Authorization\" data in request header"

Is this generated elsewhere.. or am i missing something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the access token when you perform OAuth - select the app from your existing client credentials, hit Authorize, log into your SurveyMonkey account, and it should auto-populate the 'Access Token' field.  Then copy this into the Authorization header in the form "bearer (access token)" (without the quotes or parentheses).

Cheers,

Miles

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply... how do I know what my survey_id is?  I have a basic account and setup the following survey.. http://www.surveymonkey.com/s/QKVCWDN    in the api console, im trying to do fetch the survey details.. but not sure what survey_id is (should be int)

Comment: Sorry Tyler, I missed this comment - you can get the survey_id by using get_survey_list - see the following for some documentation about it: [get_survey_list](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_survey_list)

Answer (score 0):

The authorization header works for me with `bearer XXXYYYZZ`.  Doc here: https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/requests_responses